# How to repeat an instruction in GNU assembler on Xcode 6.1.1?

Tags: xcode, assembly, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to compile a code using Xcode6.1.1(I guess with GNU assembler), with target to iPad air2(aarch64)

```
    .macro saving_callee_prsv_regi used_regi_index
      .if \used_regi_index >= 19
        i = 19
        .rept \used_regi_index - 19
          str x\i,[sp,#-8*(\i-18)]    // fail here: x\i
          i = i + 1
        .endr
      .endif
    .endm
```

But above code compile failure. I realize that "i" is symbol but not value, I find ".irp symbol,values" and write a new version.

```
    .macro saving_callee_prsv_regi_2 used_regi_index
      .if \used_regi_index >= 19
        i = 19
        .rept \used_regi_index - 19
          .irp idx, i // fail here, "i" is expression not value?!
          str x\idx,[sp,#-8*(\idx-18)]
          i = i + 1
        .endr
       .endif      
    .endm
```

while new code still fail to pass compiling, My expected result is:

when saving_callee_prsv_regi 19 -->

```
    str x19,[sp,#-8]
```

when saving_callee_prsv_regi 22 -->

```
    str x19,[sp,#-8]
    str x20,[sp,#-16]
    str x21,[sp,#-24]
    str x22,[sp,#-32]
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU assembler has been primarily developed as a backend for the C compiler, as such it lacks features for humans. The best I could come up with is the following:

```
.macro saving_callee_prsv_regi used_regi_index
     .irp i, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31
         .if \i <= \used_regi_index
             str x\i,[sp,#-8*(\i-18)]
         .endif
     .endr
.endm
```

(Adjust the list as necessary.)

Comment: thanks for your answer, it works! While from aarch64 ABI, only r19~r28 is callee-saved register, r29:FP r30:LR r31:stack-register, I am afraid that it maybe not callee's job to save them. Did I misunderstand sth?